# How to take a screenshot of uiview always in light mode

Tags: swift, uiimage, screenshot, darkmode

Hi I use this function to take a screenshot of a view

```
func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {

    // Begin context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    // Draw view in that context
    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // And finally, get image
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    if (image != nil)
    {
        return image!
    }
    return UIImage()
}
```

The problem is that, if I'm in dark mode, text is white and when I print the image, that I taken, text not appears because is white. Can I take a screenshot in light mode also when I in dark mode?

Answer (score 0):

Set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` to `.light` to force light mode for the view

```
var screenshot: UIImage {
    self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image ?? UIImage()
}
```